# Blender bevel modifier corner distortion

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I am trying to turn my mailbox into a high poly object by beveling the edges. Does anyone know how to bevel correctly so that the corners dont distort as is shown in my screenshots? (I am using a weighted bevel modifier btw). Ive inckluded pictures showing what it looked like before and after the modifier.
Thank you.[image]
[image]

Comment: Not really sure which corners you're talking about, but you could try clicking the Geometry entry in the modifier panel and changing the Miter Outer entry from the default Sharp to Arc in the dropdown which might help.

Comment: If the method John mentions does not work, it's possible you could fix this issue by drawing new connecting lines in edit mode. If you upload the file, we could inspect the topology.

Comment: @LittleAden here's the link to the file. I tried what John said and it fixed some of the bevel issue but there was still some artifact/distortion. The lowly file is on the right and the high poly is on the right (im trying to bevel). https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9ea9b06e5cddb2aca2ce5044ac01de3120211029235516/d0e1ca288cae3fedb06d3ace019efac520211029235543/8d23d4